# C# IFormFile as ZipFile

Tags: c#, zip, .net-standard, asp.net-core-1.1, iformfile

I have a REST API endpoint which receives zip file on .Net Core 1.1. I'm getting IFormFile from request like this

```
var zipFile = HttpContext.Request.Form.Files.FirstOrDefault();
```

And then I need to pass it to service method from .Net Standard 1.5, where IFormFile is not supported.

So the question is: how can I convert IFormFile to ZipFile or to some other type which is supported in Standard 1.5, or maybe there is some more proper way to operate with zip files?
Thanks!

Comment: Is the service method running in the same process as the above code?

Comment: @mjwills Yes. If you are thinking about FileStream - that can be, but what if I'll get a lot of request for a short period?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`IFormFile` is just a wrapper for the received file. You should still *read* the actual file do something about it. For example, you could read the file stream into a byte array and pass that to the service:

```
byte[] fileData;
using (var stream = new MemoryStream((int)file.Length))
{
    file.CopyTo(stream);
    fileData = stream.ToArray();
}
```

Or you could copy the stream into a physical file in the file system instead.

But it basically depends on what you actually want to do with the uploaded file, so you should start from that direction and the convert the `IFormFile` into the thing you need.

---

If you want to open the file as a ZIP and extract something from it, you could try the [`ZipArchive` constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh158268.aspx) that takes a stream. Something like this:

```
using (var stream = file.OpenReadStream())
using (var archive = new ZipArchive(stream))
{
    var innerFile = archive.GetEntry("foo.txt");
    // do something with the inner file
}
```

Comment: Yes, a good way to handle. In service, I need to get specific txt file from zip by name and then parse data from it

Comment: @RomanBorovets In that case, you could open the file stream directly as a ZipArchive and try to retrieve the file from it.